# UIAlertController from Inside the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to present UIAlertController from inside AppDelegate and I am getting all sort of errors:

I have `@import UIKit;` at the top.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here is the code:

```
  switch (accountStatus)
    case CKAccountStatusCouldNotDetermine:
    case CKAccountStatusNoAccount:
    case CKAccountStatusRestricted:

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert" message:@"This is an alert." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        break;
```

If I remove the UIAlertController line then everything is fine! The error just says Parse Issue, Expected Expression. thats it

Comment: Neither of the errors you are showing relates to the UIAlertController.

Comment: If I comment out the UIAlertController line then no errors. I fixed the switch case to be used for multiple cases. For some reason I cannot instantiate UIAlertController inside the case statement.

Comment: Please provide more complete code. What you are showing does not give enough context.

Comment: Yeah but which function is this in, when is it called,etc?

Comment: Inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate

Comment: Ok so please include that entire function in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not create a local variable in a switch statement like that without introducing a new scope. Logical ORing the enumeration values together is also probably not what you want - you can instead have the cases fall through.

```
switch (accountStatus) {

  case CKAccountStatusCouldNotDetermine:
  case CKAccountStatusCouldNoAccount:
  case CKAccountStatusCouldRestricted: {
    UIAlertController *controller = 
      [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                          message:@"This is an alert."
                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  } break;

}
```

You'll obviously need to have some kind of context to present this viewController but your code listing does not show enough to provide any further code

Comment: You got it! Thanks I will accept answer in two minutes.